# Difference between Mule's jms:consume and jms:listener

Tags: jms, mule4

Using Mule 4.4 on premise along with Apache ActiveMQ. I am trying to get a better understanding of how Mule handles messaging.

I tried searching the internet but am not finding any details about the same.

I have a `jms:listener`:

```xml
<jms:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="JMS_Config" destination="Consumer.mine2.VirtualTopic.mine.test">
    <jms:consumer-type >
        <jms:queue-consumer />
    </jms:consumer-type>
</jms:listener>
```

and I have a `jms:consume`:

```xml
<jms:consume doc:name="Consume"  config-ref="JMS_Config" destination="Consumer.mine1.VirtualTopic.mine.test">
    <jms:consumer-type >
        <jms:queue-consumer />
    </jms:consumer-type>
</jms:consume>
```

To me both seem to be doing the same job i.e. consume messages from a queue / topic. So why do we have these two components in Mule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jms listener` is a source, so using it you can trigger a flow whenever there is a new message in queue.
[image]

`jms consume` is an operation, so you can use it anywhere within a flow's execution, i.e. like a `http request` component that you put in the middle of a flow.
[image]

**Both of them will consume a message from the queue/topic**. However, when you are using a `listener` you are basically saying that "There is a queue, I do not know when a new message will come in, but whenever it comes I need to perform these actions"

When you use a `consume` operation, you are saying "I am expecting some message soon and with that I will to these actions".

Now in both cases a message may not come at all, and both have there own way to deal with it. A `listener`, since it is a source, will just not simply trigger the flow and keep on waiting. A `consume` will block your execution until a message is there, or you can configure a time out to not be blocked fore ever.

**A common use case** can be reprocessing messages from a DLQ. Generally when you use a queue, you also have a DLQ so that the messages that failed during processing, from the "main" queue, can be sent to the DLQ and reprocessed later.

Now, in this architecture, you will typically use the `jms listener` only with the main queue for the processing of the messages. And you will have a separate flow that can have a `http listener` so that you can trigger an HTTP Endpoint whenever you are ready to reprocess the messages from the DLQ. This flow with `http listener` with `consume` all the messages (probably in a loop) from the DLQ and `publish` them back to the main queue

Comment: thanks @harshank , ```jms consume``` does it also not consume  message from a queue ? also I did not understand regarding operation can you please elaborate further ?

Comment: @GettingStartedWith123 I have added a more detailed explanation. Operation means, it can be used just like a `logger` or `http request` component in the middle of the flow. A source is what is placed in the beginning of the flow and can trigger it, like `http listener`

Comment: A flow may not have a source, in which case it will never be executed unless you trigger it from another flow. A flow with only a consume would be an example.

Comment: @HarshankBansal I believe that in this case the images are helpful to keep to illustrate the differences. Could you add the XML for each flow for completeness?

Comment: great explanation and details , thanks harshank this really helps in getting an understanding . also thanks to @aled for inputs