# Difference between JMS Listener and JMS On New Message

Tags: jms, mule4

This question is related to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72810174/when-to-use-jmsconsume-and-when-to-use-jmslistener).

I am using Mule 4.4 community edition, and I was looking through the various components available for JMS in Mule. I'm confused about `JMS On new Message` and `JMS Listener`. All of the documentation for [listener](https://docs.mulesoft.com/jms-connector/1.8/jms-listener) seems to be talking about `On New Message` however the code snippets in this link shows a listener:

```xml
<jms:listener config-ref="config" destination="#[vars.destination]"/>
```

So it looks like they are both one and the same. If so, then I am confused as to why they show up separately in Mule palette as individual components.

When I dragged and dropped both of these components into their respective flows the underlying XML code still is about the listener.

Comment: They are same. The display name of `jms:listener` is `On new Message`. That's all it is to this.

Comment: thanks @HarshankBansal for the confirmation . Ideally should it not appear as two distinct components in mule palette to avoid confusion ?

Comment: It is to maintain a consistency across different modules. If you check other modules, like database, emails, SFTP or any other module. the XML DSL always have `listener` as its DSL element. And the display name should be more descriptive. For example, if you just say listener in SFTP, one might think that it is also listening to deletion of files too.

Comment: @HarshankBansal please post the answer as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. The display name of `jms:listener` is "On New Message." That's all there is to this. It is to maintain a consistency across different modules. If you check other modules like database, emails, SFTP, or any other module the XML DSL always has "listener" as its DSL element. The display name is different as they should be more descriptive then just saying "listener." For example, if you just say listener in SFTP one might think that it is also listening to deletion of files too, but it only listens to new or updated files and therefore it is more appropriate to name it "On New or Updated File."